# Android 7 ignoring Auto Updates turned OFF. Any solution?

Tags: updates, settings, application-autoupdate, disable-app

In Settings -> System apps updater, I've turned  "Auto updates" to OFF. However, I've just received a message "5 apps updated". In fact it has updated Gmail, Maps, Chrome, Google Photos and Telegram.

It has changed a number of settings on those apps WHICH I DON'T WANT TO CHANGE.

Among those apps I only want to update Telegram, so why do the rest of them update against my will and change it's configuration?? I can't believe how far is Google going on forcing users to do what they don't want to.

How can I effectively tell Android that I don't want it's updates?

EDIT:  Besides the information Matthew Read pointed, one can uninstall these updates on Settings -> Installed apps -> [Each app], so one can free a great quantity of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to Android (the operating system) are completely separate from updates to apps.  You can only control the former through the system Settings app.

To disable automatic updates for applications: Open the Play Store app, go to *Settings → Auto-update apps*, and select "Do not auto-update apps".